# How to symlink react components

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, parceljs

I'm trying to share some react components across multiple projects in an easy way. If I symlink the `.tsx` file into my web folder, node compiler fails with this error:

```
@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime' from '/Users/mahdi/dev/temp/components/Hello.tsx'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

P.S. I tried to use `yarn link` but it fails with some errors about conflict due to having multiple instances of React.

P.S. 2: `Hello.tsx` is a very simple and minimal component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export const Hello = () => {
    const [x11, setX11] = useState(0);
    return <div onClick={() => setX11(x11 + 1)}>hello4412!{x11}</div>;
};
```

Comment: The easy way is to turn them into a local package, and then make them a `file:` dependency if you only ever want them to exist on your own computer. Yes, you'll need to `npm install` every time you update them, but that's part of working on Node projects already anyway.

Comment: I think I tried this before but problem was the components were not properly packaged or sth like that. So when I imported them, browser was trying to parse my .tsx files and threw errors. I'll give it another try. Thanks

Comment: That sounds quite odd - either they install properly and your app can import them based on the name you used for the dependency entry, or they won't install and your app code will throw an error when it tries to import them. Either way, your bundle wouldn't be pointing to "loose" tsx files?